# pymongo cursor operation is too slow when mongodb is started with --auth

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

python 2.7

pymongo 2.8

mongodb 3.0.2

```
    start = time.time()
    dynamic_strategies = self.mongo.strategy.find({'enabled': 1, '$or': [{'os': os}, {'os': 'all'}]})
    print 'time used 1: ', str(time.time() - start)
    for dynamic_strategy in dynamic_strategies:
        print 'time used 2: ', str(time.time() - start)
```

`self.mongo` is something like `pymongo.MongoClient(uri)[dbname]`

OUTPUT:

time used 1:  0.000109910964966

time used 2:  0.0460259914398

or:

time used 1:  9.3936920166e-05

time used 2:  0.0606229305267

It is strange because there is only one row of data in the cursor,and even I changed the code to this:

```
    start = time.time()
    dynamic_strategies = self.mongo.strategy.find({'enabled': 1, '$or': [{'os': os}, {'os': 'all'}]})
    print 'time used 1: ', str(time.time() - start)
    strategy = dynamic_strategies[0]
    print 'time used 3: ', str(time.time() - start)
```

OUTPUT is the same as before.

And I have done some other experiences and make a conclusion:
It will take me about 50ms first when calling any methods of the cursor object `dynamic_strategies`, I don't know why. Can someone tell me why?
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The mongodb server is a local one,so it must not be the cost of network.

**UPDATE 2**: I found that only when I start mongo with command `mongod --dbpath mongodb --auth &` and connect with username/password,  the result described above occurred. If there is no authorization step, it is as fast as I expected.

Comment: are you running in a local database or is the mongod running on a remote server?

Comment: @SteveRossiter ,hi, Im running in a local database.